# How to drop a documents in a MongoDB collection, based on key and not the value?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
dbo.collection("my_database").drop();
```

So the above code will drop the entire collection called "my_database". However within this collection there are documents, each with a unique key; here is a brief sample

```
{'STN1': value1},
{'STN2': value2},
{'STN3': value3},
```

How would you drop the `{'STN1': value1}` document regardless of the value?

I have tried the following method but with no luck:

```
dbo.collection("my_database").drop({STN1: / /});
```

Comment: As the duplicate eludes to, that would be `.deleteMany({ "STN1": { "$exists": true } })`. Since [`deleteMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) ( and variants ) is for *deleting documents* as opposed to `drop()` which means the *entire collection or database* depending on which object the method is called from. Older MongoDB API used `remove()` for *documents*, but `deleteOne()` and `deleteMany()` are meant to be clearer in purpose.

Comment: Also *strongly advise* against variable key names. Something like `{ type: 1, value: "one" },{ type: 2, value: "two" } ` is a lot cleaner and more effective to query.